# Data Enrichment with Spark Jobs Failswith large dataset (Billions of Rows)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

We have a Pipeline in which we are doing data enrichment.  We aim to process 10 TB data at least.  Currently, we are only processing little less than 2percent of that data (180 GB), but we are facing memory issues.

**CLUSTER COMPONENTS**

```
• 150 cores, 570 GB RAM (10 nodes: 16 CPU, 64 GB RAM, 256 GB Disk) 
• A s3 server to store processed data in parquet format
```

**OUR SPARK CONFIG**

```
  deploy.mode = "client"
  master = "spark://192.168.x.x:7077"
  network.timeout = 864001
  default.parallelism = 450 
  sql.shuffle.partitions = 450
  sql.files.maxPartitionBytes = "128MB"

  # executor configs
  executor.memory = 19g 
  executor.memoryOverhead = 3g
  executor.instances = 30 
  executor.cores = 5 #Number of concurrent tasks an executor can run.
  // executor.heartbeatInterval = 864000000

  # driver configs
  driver.cores = 15
  driver.memory = 19g
  driver.memoryOverhead = 6g
```

**OUR USE CASE**

We currently have a part of our data (180 GB of 10 TB) stored in parquet format on S3 storage. Let’s call this data **DDD**.
We have various other file source : CSV, TXT, XLSX etc. Let’s call them F1, F2, F3, … Fn
Fn Files have various sizes ranging from some mb to 50gb.

**ENRICHMENT**
Let’s resume our data schema like this. (Really it has more 30 columns)

```
    name: String
    phone_number: ArrayType
    hobbies:ArrayType
    job_title: String
```

To enrich data, we need to groupby all columns having the same phone_number.

**OUR WORKFLOW**
Following, is our process to enrich **DDD** with **F1**

- Read DDD in **df_d** and F1 in **df_1** with `spark.read`,
- UNION the df_d and df_1 as `df_union`
- In df_union, explode phone_number column in `phone_number_exploded`
- then groupby resulting single values of `phone_number_exploded` first, And groupby `phone_number` secondly to rebuild all rows while applying `collect_set` on `hobbies` and `job` columns if not empty.
- then we save `df_union` in S3 again

**THE PROBLEM**

That worked fine, but as data grows, we started facing OOM issues. Tasked started failing with following errors:

**Error 1**

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 6 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
```

**Error2**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.copy(UnsafeRow.java:492)
```

Also, we have `AQE` enabled. It worked fine, but since we reached A Billion records per df, we started facing Skew Data issues. As saving data hangs on last take during hours sometimes.

**OUR QUESTIONS**

- Is there anything we are doing wrong?
- Is there a better way to handle our workflow? Maybe using join or any other techniques?
- How can we deal with Skew Data as AQE seems falling after reaching some quantity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adjusting executor configs, the values seem low for your cluster size.

```
# executor configs
executor.memory = 60g
executor.memoryOverhead = 3g
executor.instances = 10
executor.cores = 32
```

Comment: Thanks, @alexander, for your answer. But this configuration is unrealistic. e.g., our cluster have not sufficient resources to set executor cores at 32. We only have 16 CPU for each server.